# Remove shadow in Button

Tags: android

I created a button, set the background to `@null`, but shadow is still there.

How can I remove the shadow?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Random" />
```

Comment: Do you have a additional styles defined for the activity where this Button is added? May be a style adds the shadow? Check in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I didn't add any styles

Comment: @null works for me as well. What version of Android are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

BTW: your background as null works for me without the shadow

Comment: try that code in new android project, maybe u're right

Comment: It is very strange! In my Eclipse Button have shadow. When I publish to realy phone - Button don't have shadow... =/

Comment: I tried that and ran on emulator, works fine. Try it on smartphone maybe.

Comment: do you mean in the android designer within eclipse? You can't trust that :)

Comment: I think that is bug in Eclipse.

Comment: Check API level, maybe older buttons have shadows. Or Eclipse bug, can be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a background via a drawable.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/shadowless_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button"
    android:text="Press Me"
/>
```

and a background in the drawables folder

drawable/background_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

        <!-- view background color -->
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"></solid>

        <!-- view border color and width -->
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"></stroke>

        <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
        <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
        <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

        <!-- view background color -->
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>

        <!-- view border color and width -->
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"></stroke>

        <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
        <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
        <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]